# Web Audio API - How do I save the audio buffer to a file including all changes?

Tags: javascript, audio, web-audio-api

I made changes to an audio buffer like gain and panning, connected them to an audio context.
Now I want to save to a file with all the implemented changes.
Saving the buffer as is would give me the original audio without the changes.

Any idea of a method or a procedure existed to do that?

Comment: making changes to buffer as you say is very similar to connecting the audio context to a file sink after running it thru an encoder, see the example saving encoded web audio to a file : https://github.com/GersonRosales/Record-Audios-and-Videos-with-getUserMedia/blob/master/example_3.html#L120

Answer (score 3):

On way is to use a `MediaRecorder` to save the modified audio.

So, in addition to connecting to the destination, connect to a `MediaStreamDestinationNode`.  This node has a stream object that you can use to initialize a `MediaRecorder`.  Set up the recorder to save the data when data is available.  When you're down recording, you have a blob that you can then download.

Many details are missing here, but you can find out how to use a MediaRecorder using the [MDN example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder#example).

Comment: Unfortunately, `OfflineAudioContext` doesn't support `MediaStreamDestinationNode`

Comment: If you're using a `MediaStreamDestinationNode`, you'll have to use an `AudioContext` and a `MediaRecorder` to save the data.

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution, with OfflineAudioContext.
Here is an example with adding a gain change to my audio and saving it.
On the last line of the code I get the array buffer with the changes I made.
From there, I can go on saving the file.

```
let offlineCtx = new OfflineAudioContext(this.bufferNode.buffer.numberOfChannels, this.bufferNode.buffer.length, this.bufferNode.buffer.sampleRate);
let obs = offlineCtx.createBufferSource();
obs.buffer = this.buffer;
let gain = offlineCtx.createGain();
gain.gain.value = this.gain.gain.value;
obs.connect(gain).connect(offlineCtx.destination);
obs.start();
let obsRES = this.ctx.createBufferSource();
await offlineCtx.startRendering().then(r => {
  obsRES.buffer = r;
});
```