# Normalizing audio in javascript AND saving result to file

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api, audiocontext

Ive been playing around with [JS normalizer](https://github.com/est31/js-audio-normalizer) to bring widely different volume recordings to play at a fairly constant volume.

This code is doing it's job quite nicely.
My final goal though is to allow the user to record audio with the mic, then save the **normalized** audio to a file (I don't need to play it back, And I don't need the original recording once i have the normalized version of it).

Does anyone know how can this be accomplished?

BTW, since i first used this sample chrome now refuses to let the `AudioContext` object be set without user interaction, so a quick workaround is to move the declaration:
`var audioCtx = new AudioContext();`
to the beginning of `normalizedAudioElement` function

Cheers!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66739369/web-audio-api-how-do-i-save-the-audio-buffer-to-a-file-including-all-changes